# Maintaining order of colours in shiny plot created with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, colors

[[image: 3 colours in legend2 colours in legend]

I am trying to develop a shiny app and I am using a slider input to control the colour parameter defined in geom_point() using a  series of conditional ifelse statements according to the code below.

The code is working, however the colours are not consistent when the legend goes from 3 colours to 2 colours. For example, "Down" is Green, "Unchanged" is Grey and "Up" is Red. As I vary the input$FC, the legend changes to 2 colours and now, Unchanged is Green and UP is grey. I would like to maintain the colour coding consistent regardless of how many colour are shown in the legend. Here's my code for ui and server:
library(shiny)

```
ui <- fluidPage(


    titlePanel("Plotting parameters:"),

  
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("x.axis", "Select X axis:", 
                        choices = c("log2FC", "log2.Control.Counts", "log2.LPS.Counts")),
            selectInput("y.axis", "Select Y axis:", 
                        choices = c('neg.log10.P.value', "log2.Control.Counts", "log2.LPS.Counts")),
            sliderInput("P.value",
                        "Adjust p.value",
                        min = 0,
                        max = 0.5,
                        value = 0.01,
                        step = 0.001), 
            sliderInput("FC",
                        "Adjust fold change:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 7,
                        value = 2,
                        step = 0.5),
        ),

  
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("scatter")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$scatter <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = exp, aes_string( x=input$x.axis, y=input$y.axis))+
                geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2.2, aes(fill = ifelse((FC<(-input$FC) & P.value < input$P.value), "Down", 
                                                ifelse((FC>(input$FC) & P.value<input$P.value), "UP", "Unchanged"))))+
            geom_vline(xintercept = c(-log2(input$FC), log2(input$FC)), linetype = "dashed") +
            geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(input$P.value), linetype = "dashed")+
            scale_fill_manual(values = c("Green", "Grey", "Red"))+
            guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Legend"))
                 
                                             
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please make your code minimal and reproducible.

Comment: Perhaps use `scale_fill_manual(values = c("Green", "Grey", "Red"), limits = c('Down', 'Unchanged', 'Up'))`. This is a guess, since I can't check without any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify colors with `scale_*_manual(values=...)`, the colors are assigned to the aesthetic variable in your dataset according to the ordering of the levels of that particular factor.  You're assigning values "on the fly", so to speak, with the `ifelse()` part of the code, but the general rule still applies here.  After the values of "Down", "Up" or "unchanged" are assigned, the levels for that factor are used to associate with your colors indicated.  If not otherwise specified, the ordering of the levels would default to alphabetical, which is why the order appears "Down", "Unchanged", and "Up" (although that can be changed in your legend if you wish...).

The easy solution here is to know that you can pass a **named vector** to `scale_*_manual()` instead of just a vector of colors.  This will define the colors associated with specific level names, regardless of whether they exist in the final plot.  In other words, the following should work in all cases:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Down"="Green", "Unchanged"="Grey", "Up"="Red"))+
```

Ordering does not matter here, since the `values` named vector is essentially used as a mini lookup table.  So, this works too:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Unchanged"="Grey", "Down"="Green", "Up"="Red"))+
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a clear answer and simple workaround!